# How to discover repeating code lines with PMD

Tags: code-coverage, apex, pmd, code-duplication, cpd

A popular attempt to bypass Salesforce Apex code coverage rules are code busters where one statement is used in thousands of repeating lines.

We have found variations like `i=1;` or `a++;` or `a=b;` with endless variations for the variable name. All have in common that two (or more) consecutive lines (excluding empty or comments) are identical.

How can I discover those in PMD?

Answer (score 1):

This sound more like a use case for the copy paste detector. This is a separate tool also available from PMD:
https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.12.0/pmd_userdocs_cpd.html

However, CPD is focused on finding duplicated code between different files, whereas you seem to be looking for duplicated code *within one* file.

Comment: I’m specifically searching for consecutive identical lines. I’m aware of CPD - we had lots of fun with it (and some red faces). Doesn’t really work for that use case